# rtpvp8depay + rtpvp8pay appear to introduce artifacts on Janus Gateway

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, gstreamer-1.0, vp8, janus-gateway

A VP8 stream comes from Janus Videoroom plugin with restreaming to 10002/10004 locally. From there, it's picked up with the following gstreamer pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc \
caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,encoding-name=(string)VP8,payload=100" \
address=127.0.0.1 port=10004 ! \
rtpvp8depay ! rtpvp8pay  ! \
udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5004
```

and sent to Streaming plugin. As you can see, no transcoding here, just depayloading and payloading. resulting video breaks down into artifacts on some keyframes, approximately once in 10 keyframes, only to be fixed on next keyframe.

if i remove depay and pay, simply forwarding on rtp level, to get this

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc \
caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,encoding-name=(string)VP8,payload=100" \
address=127.0.0.1 port=10004 ! \
udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5004
```

it never happens.

i understand this is not the Janus issue but a gstreamer issue. but maybe anyone has an idea what could be the problem? this has been very reliably tested, the problem is easy to reproduce in the former case and never happens in the latter.

Of course, the goal of what i am doing is transcoding, and there was a lot more in the setup and the pipeline before i boiled it down to this level. Reproduced on Janus installed on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 machine with all out-of-the-box settings.

update:

```
export GST_DEBUG="rtp*:4";
```

revealed this error message which drops out each time artifacts appear:

```
rtpbasedepayload gstrtpbasedepayload.c:473:gst_rtp_base_depayload_handle_buffer:
<rtpvp8depay0> 12 <= 100, dropping old packet
```

with the number which is "12" fluctuating being typically between 5 and 12.

Comment: Remembering this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56788387/h264-webrtc-video-streamed-from-ffmpeg-through-janus-is-very-choppy-on-playback/56823716#56823716, i tried to set "mtu=1200" in rtpvp8pay options (default is 1400 which is kinda scary), but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

This was the fix:

rtpjitterbuffer latency=50 !

before rtpvp8depay.

Logically, the order of packets is the same by that point as the one that came through the internet between the sending browser and Janus. If we don't depay+pay, it goes the same way to the receiving browser that's connected to Streaming plugin, and it has it's own jitter buffer so able to fix order, but if we do depay+pay here, there is no buffer so these packets are dropped, resuling in broken frames.

And yes, i got back transcoding and all the rest of my pipeline and all of other bells and whistles that were around, and it still works fine.

Comment: Also "latency" value doesn't impact things much being between 50 and 200. So i left it at just "rtpjitterbuffer" with no options in the end, if latency end to end is higher than in case with 50 then only by very insignificant value. 0..40ms.

Comment: "latency" seems to be upper limit. on a very bad internet connections artifacts reproduced but vanished when i set "latency" to 1000. Actual end to end latency increased to only 270ms from the initial 200 though, and it is still 200 on the better internet.