# Mediasoup inject stream freezes

Tags: webrtc, mediasoup

I am using the following ffmpeg command to inject an rtmp stream to mediasoup.

```
ffmpeg \
  -re \
  -v info \
  -stream_loop -1 \
  -i rtmp://3.126.121.45:1935/live/stream \
  -map 0:a:0 \
  -acodec libopus -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 \
  -map 0:v:0 \
  -c:v libvpx -minrate 2500k -maxrate 2500k -b:v 2500k -r 30 -g 60 -max_delay 0 -bf 0 -deadline realtime -cpu-used 1 \
  -f tee \
"[select=a:f=rtp:ssrc=11111111:payload_type=101]rtp://52.29.30.225:41299?rtcpport=40612&pkt_size=1300|[select=v:f=rtp:ssrc=22222222:payload_type=102]rtp://52.29.30.225:44083?rtcpport=48791&pkt_size=1300"
```

But the video seems to freeze randomly and plays again. Any idea how I can fix this? Tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69437197/ffmpeg-inject-video-to-mediasoup-only-can-play-first-frame) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56788387/h264-webrtc-video-streamed-from-ffmpeg-through-janus-is-very-choppy-on-playback) with no luck.

**Update:** Seems like it is the problem of RTP retransmission when some packets are lost. Unfortunately, ffmpeg doesn't fare well with RTP streaming as mentioned [here](https://mediasoup.discourse.group/t/very-high-packet-loss-with-ffmpeg-broadcasting/322). Meaning ffmpeg doesn't support retransmission mechanism like nack, pli etc. So considering gstreamer instead as suggested in the mediasoup discourse discussion.